How to display different forms of Farsi letter as a single Letter
How can I display the connected forms of a letter by itself? For example, I'm working on a flashcard webpage to study Farsi as a personal project and when trying to make a flashcard for the alphabet I tried making a card for the connected form of the letter "ی" (which looks like the letter on the right in "یش") From what I can tell both of the forms of the letter have the same unicode character and I guess the browser and other apps know how to interpret the same character in the correct way depending on context.
I came up with a way to display the letter by itself but was wondering if there is a better way that doesn't use css. I can do something like this <span style="color:white">ش</span><span>ی</span> where the background color is white so the ش isn't visible.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you type Shift+J with a Farsi keyboard, it will insert:
ـ
If you type it after ی, it will appear like یـ
